# Error while reading JSON to keep in sqllite

Tags: python, json

I am actually trying to get a json file and keep in sqllite.
when I am reading data from JSON I am geting Errors.

My Data is (in a file) :

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1bd"},"a":1,"a1":"city1","b":1,"C":21,"D":"ECE","E":""}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b2"},"a":2,"a1":"city2","b":14,"C":31,"D":"ECE","E":""}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b3"},"a":3,"a1":"city3","b":12,"C":41,"D":"ECE","E":""}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b4"},"a":4,"a1":"city4","b":11,"C":51,"D":"ECE","E":""}
```

My Code is :

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Logs1.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
    json_data = json.loads(json_file.read())

#Aim of the block is to get the list of the columns in the JSON file.
    columns = []
    column = []
    for data in json_data:
        column = list(data.keys())
        print("the value is "+column)
        for col in column:
            if col not in columns:
                columns.append(col)
                print("the value is col"+col)

#Here we get values of the columns in the JSON file in the right order.   
    value = []
    values = [] 
    for data in json_data:
        for i in columns:
            value.append(str(dict(data).get(i)))   
        values.append(list(value)) 
        value.clear()
```

Error I am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sqlliteutility.py", line 10, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(json_file.read())
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 93)
```

I am writting this utility so that I can keep this data in SQLlite

Comment: Is your file formatted such that each record is on its own line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format.  Each line is a JSON record.  Process each line individually:

```
import json
import pprint

with open('data.jsonl', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]

pprint.pprint(data,width=120)
```

Output:

```
[{'C': 21, 'D': 'ECE', 'E': '', '_id': {'$oid': '5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1bd'}, 'a': 1, 'a1': 'city1', 'b': 1},
 {'C': 31, 'D': 'ECE', 'E': '', '_id': {'$oid': '5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b2'}, 'a': 2, 'a1': 'city2', 'b': 14},
 {'C': 41, 'D': 'ECE', 'E': '', '_id': {'$oid': '5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b3'}, 'a': 3, 'a1': 'city3', 'b': 12},
 {'C': 51, 'D': 'ECE', 'E': '', '_id': {'$oid': '5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b4'}, 'a': 4, 'a1': 'city4', 'b': 11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json data isn't formatted properly. This is probably how it should look:

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1bd"},"a":1,"a1":"city1","b":1,"C":21,"D":"ECE","E":""},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b2"},"a":2,"a1":"city2","b":14,"C":31,"D":"ECE","E":""},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b3"},"a":3,"a1":"city3","b":12,"C":41,"D":"ECE","E":""},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e15608e952f72ddc69cc1b4"},"a":4,"a1":"city4","b":11,"C":51,"D":"ECE","E":""}]
```

Note the commas separating the records and brackets at the beginning and end of the data

Comment: Thank you I tried that also its not working. I am actually exporting the data from mongodb using mongodbimport and it is not having [ and ]. I added that in my file manually still see error. is there a way we can get around without [ and ] and follow the data from mongodbimport directly

Answer (score 0):

you can also export the data in CSV format with the selective field. which would be easier to digest through python.

```
mongoexport -d test -c viva --query ''  --type csv --out vida.csv --fields a,b,c
```

Comment: Thank you. I cannot use csv as I need json data only to be processed